# How to open whatsapp desktop instead of web using C#

Tags: c#, desktop

I need C# code to open the WhatsApp desktop application instead of open WhatsApp on the web.

I tried

```
Process.Start("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + textBox1.Text);
```

but it opens WhatsApp on the web, instead of the WhatsApp Desktop application.

I want to open this link in desktop WhatsApp application

Comment: Is there a WhatrsApp Desktop App? Didon't know that.

Comment: `Process.Start`  is the right call to make - but you need to provide a **local on-disk location** of the `.exe` file for the Whatsapp Desktop app - not a web address ...

Answer (score 2):

The desktop version of WhatsApp can be found in `%LocalAppData%\WhatsApp\Whatsapp.exe`.

You get the environment variable with

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

Use [`Path.Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0) to get the backslashes right when combining multiple paths.

Note that the executable above likely just starts another version of WhatsApp.exe. The latest version seems to be in the default key of the Registry at

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp\shell\open\command
```

Starting point for an implementation: [`Registry.ClassesRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.classesroot?view=net-5.0).

Comment: butt how can we execute the link in the whatsapp
my main purpose to open whatsapp

Comment: "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + textBox1.Text

Comment: "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + textBox1.Text

i just wanna execute this link in whatsapp

Comment: @SohailAmjad: you can either open a URL in a browser or you can start Whatsapp. Maybe this is a XY-problem. What do you expect the link to do?

Comment: i need that link execute and open the chat of the given number through text box 
chat directly open in desktop WhatsApp not in the web WhatsApp

Comment: @SohailAmjad: It's definitely not possible with a HTTPS link. And I don't think that's possible through command line parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `whatsapp` protocol:

```
var process = $"whatsapp://send?phone={textBox1.Text}";
Process.Start(process);
```

You can append the `text` argument to send a text:

`whatsapp://send?phone=5555555555&text=hello`

Comment: UseFull

At least it opens chat head and what about if i wanna also share text to phone number 

as this link do for web

Process.Start("https://wa.me/{textBox1.Tex}?text={textBox2.Text}");

Comment: https : // wa.me / number?text=message

Comment: This will open the Whatsapp desktop app with provided message , but we need to press enter key to send that message ! any other way to send message without clicking send button in messenger?

Answer (score 1):

This the updated code for web WhatsApp to send also the message

```
 string phoneNumber = textBox1.Text;
 string message = textBox2.Text;

        // Prepare the URL with the pre-filled phone number and message
        string url = "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(phoneNumber) +
                     "&text=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(message);

        // Open the URL in the default web browser
        Process.Start(url);


        // Wait for the browser to open and load the WhatsApp Web
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // Adjust the delay if needed

        // Simulate pressing the "Enter" key to send the message
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Use Process.Start("explorer.exe", $"tel:{phone_number}");
IMPORTANT: make sure to configure windows default apps to handle URL:tel with WhatsApp.

```
string phone_number = "";//<phone_number>
Process.Start("explorer.exe", $"tel:{phone_number}");
```

Option 2
Use the web URL https://wa.me/<phone_number>, and make sure to configure your url to 'always allow' when it tries to open the WhastApp App

```
string phone_number = "";//<phone_number>
Process.Start("explorer.exe", $"https://wa.me/{phone_number}");
```